# How do I get shared folders working under Fedora 19 (guest) with open-vm-tools?

Tags: vmware, fedora

Fedora 19 includes the open-vm-tools package.  This was installed by default under a VMware Fusion host.  Everything works except for shared folders.

I'd rather not install from source, since that would mean compiling every time there's a kernel change.

Answer (score 1):

According to:
[Bug 988641](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=988641) - Cannot mount vmhgfs shares in virtual guest with open-vm-tools, open-vm-tools contains user space components.  I'd have to build from source, or install VMware Tools, until they move that functionality from the kernel driver.

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora 19/mate installation under Fusion on my Mac, the Mac shows up in the 'Network' section of the file browser.  I can simply click 'Imac/remote login' and there is my whole Mac machine.